# Unable to reach Expo servers. Falling back to using the cached dependency map (bundledNativeModules.json) from the package "expo"

Tags: react-native, expo

I have used the following commands and all of them show the same error:

- `npm start`
- `yarn expo start` &
- `npx expo start`

Unable to reach Expo servers. Falling back to using the cached dependency map *(bundledNativeModules.json)* from the package `"expo"` installed in your project.

```
FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/versions/latest failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/versions/latest failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\LW775GV\dev\test\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1505:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:502:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```